# How do i pass data values to modals using react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on using modals to accept form inputs on a react project

here is the plan component

`plan/index.js`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Pay from '../Pay';


const Plan = () => {

  const [payModal, setPayModal] = useState(false);
  const [planMode, setPlanMode] = useState(true);

  return (
  <main class="main">

    {payModal && <Pay setOpenPayModal={setPayModal} />}

  <div class="plan">
   <div>
    <a class="plans" onClick={() => {setPayModal(true);}}>plan A</a>
              
    <div class="plan">
          <span class="plan">{!planMode ? "$19.99" : "$9.99"}</span>
          <span class="plan">{!planMode ? "month" : "year"}</span>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div>
    <a class="plans" onClick={() => {setPayModal(true);}}>plan B</a>
              
    <div class="plan">
          <span class="plan">{!planMode ? "$29.99" : "$19.99"}</span>
          <span class="plan">{!planMode ? "month" : "year"}</span>
    </div>
   </div>


  </div>
  </main>
  );
};
export default Plan;
```

as you can see on the line `{payModal && <Pay setOpenPayModal={setPayModal} />}` where i call the pay modal component from the plan component and it opens up the modal

here is the pay component which is the modal component

`pay/index.js`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";



function Pay({ setOpenPayModal }) {

  const [billingDetails, setBillingDetails] = useState({
    price: "",
    : "",
  });

  return (

    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal">
        <div class="close">
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setOpenPayModal(false);
            }}
          >
          </button>
        </div>


        <div class="modal">

        <form class="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <fieldset class="form">

                <Field
                label="Price"
                id="price"
                type="text"
                value={billingDetails.price}
                onChange={(e) => {
                    setBillingDetails({ ...billingDetails, price: e.target.value });
                }}
                />

                <Field
                label="Frequency"
                id="frequency"
                type="text"
                value={billingDetails.frequency}
                onChange={(e) => {
                    setBillingDetails({ ...billingDetails, frequency: e.target.value });
                }}
                />

            </fieldset>
            <button class="pay" onClick={handleSubmitPay}>
                Pay
            </button>
        </form>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Pay;
```

The issue is I want to be able to pass the values `price` and `frequency` from the plan component to the pay modal component

**for example for plan A is `price="$19.99"` and `frequency="year"`, so based on the button clicked on the plan component page, those values get passed to the pay modal component in a dynamic way**

how do I achieve this using react hooks?

Answer (score 1):

You can use contexts to pass, but in this case I don't think it's the best option. What I really recommend is passing the state variable through the props.

```
{payModal && <Pay setOpenPayModal={setPayModal} price={price} frequency={frequency} />}
```

I usually use the Context (useContext) when I need values and various components, for example:

- I need to save the user id that is logged in to various components, and instead of getting it from the server every time I need it, I keep it saved in my context that I created, so I can make the call only once.
  Documentation-> https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: can you explain how to use the contexts to pass? and why its not best option?

Comment: can you modify your answer with more details on how to use usecontext?

Comment: Added an example of why I would use context and left the link to the documentation

Comment: using usestate works(not sure why i never thought of that to be honest) but if you can provide how to use usecontext in your answer, will accept as answer and that will really be appreicated..tried toe usecontext and values not getting passed